# Checking if Inserting values in order into an initially empty minimum binary heap is correct

Tags: python, binary-heap

Can someone tell me if I have produced the right minimum binary heap after inserting these values in order into an initially empty minimum binary heap?

`[23, 41, 19, 59, 10, 15, 40]`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is the correct result for that input.

The heap evolves as follows:

```
       23
```

```
      _23
     /  
   41
```

```
      _19_
     /    \
   41      23
```

```
      _19_
     /    \
   41      23
  /
 59
```

```
      _10_
     /    \
   19      23
  /  \
 59  41
```

```
      _10_
     /    \
   19      15
  /  \    /
 59  41  23
```

```
      _10_
     /    \
   19      15
  /  \    /  \
 59  41  23  40
```